# Fastest way to build this string

Tags: javascript, performance

say I have an array of objects with html strings inside (there are other things, but i'm specifically focusing on the html property of each object. e.g.

```
var items = [{
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}, {
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}, {
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}];
```

I need to build a string using all of these strings and I need them in the same order they're given to me, so a reverse while loop is out.

is there anything faster at building the html than the following?

```
var html = [];
for (var i = 0, itemLen = items.length; i < itemLen; i++) {
    html.push(items[i].html)
}
output.innerHTML = html.join('');
```

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to profile different approaches: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: Here is the test for different approaches: http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-perf

Comment: Why would you do a _reverse_ `while` loop?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit technically they're the fastest loops:  `var i = arr.length; while (i--) {}`, the only problem is that if i used it to build this string, it would be in reverse order.. so i would have to reverse the data then loop through it, which ends up being more expensive than a regular for loop..

Comment: @tester: Why are they the fastest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faster would be:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0, itemLen = items.length; i < itemLen; ++i)
    html += items[i].html;
output.innerHTML = html;
```

Edit:

This is faster:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0, itemLen = items.length; i < itemLen; html += items[i++].html);
```

Comment: ^ win check the url that Felix posted above: http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-perf

Comment: I'm sorry, my version wasn't faster... . But now I've got a version faster ("another version"): http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-perf/5

Comment: Oh for the love of Pete lmao yes, yes you did haha I really don't know that the extra 0.000001 teraflops of CPU we're saving are really going to impact the end user that much, but kudos lol I think you've boiled it down to its rawest form there :P

Comment: It still falls in the error margin though, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is much faster than yours

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0, itemLen = items.length; i < itemLen; i++) {
    html += items[i].html;
}
output.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: ++i would be even more faster than i++.

Comment: @user1150525: I doubt it would make a notable difference.

Comment: Don't forget to create a variable to hold `items.length` so there isn't a penalty on the lookup of the `length` parameter.

Comment: @skyronic I'm pretty sure he's doing that at the beginning of the for loop. the variables are chained

Comment: But your's isn't the fastest.

Comment: @user1150525, Of course it is. Check from the very same report you posted.

Comment: The topic is old by now, but it doesn't matter: My ++i version: http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-perf/4 ; My [i++] version: http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-perf/5 Run the test for 10 times and you will see that my versions are more often faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0, itemLen = items.length; i < itemLen; i++) {
    html += items[i].html;
}
output.innerHTML = html
```

Simply concatenating to a string would be faster than building an array and imploding it as that technically double loops the data instead of looping it once.

Comment: nope, mine's is faster :D. ++i is faster than i++, but thats an extremly small difference.

Comment: just curious, wouldn't ++i miss the zero index?

Comment: @user1150525: I only believe that yours is faster if you show me a http://jsperf.com/ test which proofs it.

Comment: I added it to yours Felix and it did come out faster for me by about 1.5% lol marginal as stated in the claim, but still faster as ++i **only** increments the variable and i++ technically reads it and then increments it :P

Comment: @Brian: Yeah I saw it. In Chrome, the difference is even less and falls into the error margin (or however you call it). As I said, it only makes a difference if you can actually *see* a difference ;)

Comment: @FelixKling agreed lol :P on technicality alone though user1150525 definitely won the race haha

Comment: Sorry for my other comments Brian, I didn't saw, that you made more comments here. (Show 3 more comments....). I edited my solution, now its faster than before.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick too:

```
var items = [
    {html: '<div>test</div>'},
    {html: '<div>test</div>'},
    {html: '<div>test</div>'}],
    newString = "";
items.forEach(function(item) {
    newString = newString + item.html;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/H7HHM/).

Comment: But its slower than the normal way.

Comment: @user1150525: It's simply more proper since we have objects as associative arrays involved. In terms of speed, you're right, but I'm just giving you another option.

Answer (score -1):

Warning this is solution could cause a lot problems. But it does give a relatively fast way to do what you want.

```
var items = [{
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}, {
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}, {
    html: '<div>test</div>'
}];

Object.prototype.toString=function(){return this.html};

items.join('');
```

If there is anyway to control the object that gets added to the array in the first place then you can change only that object's prototype which won't mess with the global Object.